# are there any open source tools to test web services?

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

I need an open source test tool to do a  data driven testing against Web services other than SoapUI as it doesn't support Data Driven Testing in the free version

Answer (score 0):

**SoapUI:**

In free version of soapui with using groovyscript we can implement datadriven testing.

**Useful links:**

http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/12/road-to-reading-data-from-excel-file-in.html

https://lgsofttest.blogspot.in/2014/06/datadriven-testing-in-soapui-open.html

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: We are using soapui free version for datadriven testing of webservices its nice  We can do lot more with groovyscript.